# Automate a schedule task at streamlit

Tags: python, heroku, schedule, streamlit

I currently have a deployed application at heroku that uses streamlit framework for data analysis. However the page opens very slow since every time a user opens the website, it starts to download a CSV data.

So, my goal is to atomate a task to download the CSV data to make the website lightweight. Is there any way to use for example, schedule library into streamlit to download the CSV data daily?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution using only Streamlit.

I had the same problem and managed to get it fixed by creating another script to run via a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Your script:

```py
# create a python script that will download the 
# csv data
# bear in mind, what I write is an example, 
# since it is a Python script, you can do whatever you want ;)

def create_csv():
    with open("/path/to/csv", "w") as f:
        f.write("a,b,c\n1,2,3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_csv()
```

And you make this script run every hour (for example):

```
crontab -e
```

Inside the opened file:

```
0 * * * *  cd /path/to/script && python script.py
```

You can check the cron syntax [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_*_*_*_*).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but the last answer is relatively new so...

My solution is to use `streamlit.cache`

You can see detail usage in this [documentation link](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching)